# Convert HTML5 to Wordpress theme

Tags: posts, theme-development

I designed a HTML5 template. Now I want convert that template to a WordPress theme. I was converting the main page (index.php). Now I want two pages, one to create a section in my theme for a blog which shows a summary of the posts (4 lines from each posts). The other one for showing that post open with all lines and all attachments.

P.S.: I designed those pages in HTML. Now I just want to make that connect to WordPress

Comment: Have a look at [the docs on template files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/) and [the template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with tutorials on web to convert HTML5 to WordPress. The steps are too exhaustive to be covered in an answer here. However, [here's a link](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/converting-html-sites-to-wordpress-sites) for you to get started.

Also, don't forget to check out WordPress Codex, the documentation which will guide you through WP functions, standards & APIS.